# When is our keyword necessary at all?

Tags: perl, variables, built-in

```
perl -e 'use strict;use warnings;$a=2;print $a'
```

It seems no warning is reported when I declare a global variable without `our`,so when is this keyword necessary?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$a` and `$b` are special cases - they are reserved for `sort` (e.g. `sort { $a <=> $b }`) and shouldn't be used for your own variable names - try again using something else and see what happens!

Answer (score 11):

From [perlvar:](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

```
   $a
   $b      Special package variables when using "sort()", see "sort" in
           perlfunc.  Because of this specialness $a and $b don't need to
           be declared (using "use vars", or "our()") even when using the
           "strict 'vars'" pragma.
```